# Binary representation of Symbolic Link

Tags: files, symlink

I am working on a ctf and I want to upload a Symbolic Link that points to a file instead of uploading a regular file.

I want to know if there is there a way to build a symlink by hand or to copy the binary of a symlink that has already been created?

Comment: Put the link target in a file and set the symlink bit.

Comment: Use `readlink()` to read the original link, and `symlink()` to create the new one.